# Settings.canDrawOverlays for API < 23

Tags: android

Since I can use `Settings.canDrawOverlays` to check if the user granted this permission on API >= 23, how I can check if the user have it on older APIS?

Does this permission is automically granted on API < 23 and no need to check for it?

Currently, I start my service only on API 23+ after the permission are granted.

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void checkDrawOverlayPermission() {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            /** check if we already  have permission to draw over other apps */
            if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
                /** if not construct intent to request permission */
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                        Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
                /** request permission via start activity for result */
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
            } else {
                startService(new Intent(this, ChatHeadService.class));
            }
        }
    }
```

But what if the user is on API <= 22? How I can make sure the application wont crash and my service will start?

Comment: There is no need to ask for this permission below Marshmallow so it is safe to run your service on those systems. You can draw overlays by default there.

Comment: Cool thank you@ @mhenryk

Comment: Of course you need the permission in manifest but that is true for every platform and I assume you have that covered. For reference it is the _<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>_ permission

Comment: also ,when you publish your app and it will be signed by Google play store the permission is granted automatically.

Comment: Try this it may be work stackoverflow.com/a/41221852/5488468

Answer (score 3):

Overlay permission is only required for Marshmallow (API 23) and above. In previous APIs this permission is provided by default.